# Как найти сумму каждого второго числа в диапазоне? Java

Tags: java

Например,

[1, 2] => 1

[1, 3] => 1 + 3 = 4

[1, 5] => 1 + 3 + 5 = 9

[0, 5] => 0 + 2 + 4 = 6

````
    public static int sum(int a, int b) {
        int sum = 0;
      for(int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
          if(?????) {
              sum += i;
          }
      }
      return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = test.sum(1, 5);
        System.out.println(result);```
    }
**Ответ должен получиться 9**
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте внутри условия `if` оператор `%` - остаток от деления. В вашем случае нужно использовать остаток от деления на 2 и сравнить его либо с 0, либо с 1 в зависимости от того четное или нечетное число a.

Либо есть более простой способ без использования оператора `if`.
Нужно немного подправить условия цикла `for(int i = a; i <= b; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = a; i <= b; i += 2) {
                        ^^^^^^
```

---

```
  if (i % 2 == a % 2) {
```

Comment: А я хотел только подсказать(

Comment: Большое спасибо !!!